# Alterar os cenários com loop

Tags: c

Como eu faço para criar um loop no Processing que alterne entre três ou mais cenários (verão, inverno e outono) quando o meu objeto (carro) chegar na borda da janela?

Comment: Isso é de Unity?

Comment: Nao, a linguagem e processing. Mas um exemplo em Java, ja me ajudaria muito.

Comment: Pode mostrar o código de uma das funções `scenarioXXXXX`? A solução ideal seria você ter uma array de cenários, mas pra propor isso precisaríamos saber mais sobre o que acontece nessas funções.

Comment: Coloquei todo o código que faz mais sentido para entender o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um jeito de fazer, não muito bonito mas que funciona:

1. Nas declarações de variáveis inclua:

   ```
   int season = 0; // 0=summer, 1=fall, 2=winter
   ```
2. Crie este novo método:

   ```
   void changeSeason() {
       // Gira o índice da estação atual
       if(++season > 2) season = 0;

       // Desenha o cenário correspondente
       if(season === 0) {
           scenarioSummer();
       } else if(season === 1) {
           scenarioFall();
       } else if(season === 2) {
           scenarioWinter();
       }
   }
   ```
3. E o método `draw` ficaria assim:

   ```
   void draw() {
       timeFrame = frameCount % width;

       // Se chegou no fim da tela
       if(timeFrame === 0) {
           changeSeason(); 
       }
   }
   ```